# MYSQL UPDATE query for multiple values

Tags: mysql

Looking to update a table from values in another table. The tables are joined on a person's first and last name. The issue is we have duplicate records where we are trying to concatenate a value for each record, however when the query goes off it only finds the first record. Table1 and Table2 both contain around 20k records.

Current query

```
UPDATE table1, table2 SET table1.value = CONCAT(table1.pet,",",table2.pet) 
WHERE table1.fName = table2.fName AND table1.lName = table2.lName;
```

Table1 Example

```
fName  lName   pet
===================
John   Doe     bird
Jane   Doe     bird
```

Table2 Example

```
fName lName  pet
===================
John  Doe     dog
Jane  Doe     dog
John  Doe     fish
John  Doe     cat
```

Expected Results in Table1

```
fName lName  pet
===================
John  Doe     bird,dog,fish,cat
Jane  Doe     bird,dog
```

Results we are currently getting

```
fName lName  pet
===================
John  Doe     bird,dog
Jane  Doe     bird,dog
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - using `group_concat()` function

```
update Table1 a
join
(
select fName,lName, group_concat(pet) as pet1
from Table2
group by fName,lName
)b on a.fName=b.fName and a.lName=b.lName
set a.pet=concat(a.pet,',',pet1)
```

Comment: group_concat have a text limit, If this was small on his server, this could cause a trouble.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also

```
 UPDATE Table1  X SET 
X.Column1=Y.column2
from(
select Column2 from tabel2
where column3=column4 
) Y where X.column4=Y.column4
```